# Pull data from HealthKit for a specific time of day

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, healthkit

I want to pull blood sugar data from lunchtime only (or just a specific time period from each day). I know how to query data from only the past 30 days etc. But is there a way to query only from a certain time period each day?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(past, endDate:pastAnotherdate, options: .None)
```

Comment: This is only for the dates, I need it with a certain time period each day.

Comment: Create multiple predicates with multiple dates and ran the query.